# SQL Server 2008 query to select data from XML with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have next XML:

```
SET @MyXML = 
'
<pairs>
  <p>
    <Name>France</Name>
    <Val>Paris</Val>
  </p>
  <p>
    <Name>England</Name>
    <Val>London</Val>
  </p>
  <p>
    <Name>Spain</Name>
    <Val>Madrid</Val>
  </p>
</pairs>
'
```

I need to get data from this XML in this way - I've set parameter "England" and get "London". My code is next, but it's not working:

```
SELECT
  Tab.Col.query('p/.[(Val)[1] cast as xs:string? = "England"]') AS [Capital]
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('//pairs') Tab(Col)
```

What I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XQuery object is incorrectly constructed. This will get the `<p>` which has the `<name>` as `"England"` and then the return the `<Val>` tag.

```
SELECT
  Tab.Col.value('((p[Name="England"]/Val/text())[1])', 'varchar(max)') AS [Capital]
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('//pairs') Tab(Col)
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! And how can I get just `London` , not the `<Val>London</Val>` ?

Comment: @ViktorUnderoath as pointed out  in several answers you should use `.value()` instead of `.query()`. The second will return a (part of the) XML tree, the first returns just the value. If you are interested in one particular value only, there's no need for `.nodes()` at all...

Comment: @ViktorUnderoath check the edit.. if it works, plz upvote and mark as answer

Comment: @SujeetSinha, your answer works, but please allow me some hints. As `pairs` is the root element, there is no need for `.nodes()` Please have a look at my one-liner. If there might be more than one `p` with the Name of "England", you **must** use `.nodes(/pairs/p)`. Because your `[1]` would return only the first in any case. And if you know, that there's only one, there's no need for `.nodes()`...

Comment: @Shnugo you are right.. i just happen to use the data and query given by Viktor at the time, one upvote from my end!

Comment: @SujeetSinha same here :-) When trying to be the first one is sometimes to fast. My first query did also just correct the OP's query, same flaws there... Thx and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You try it a bit to complicated:

```
DECLARE  @MyXML XML = 
N'<pairs>
  <p>
    <Name>France</Name>
    <Val>Paris</Val>
  </p>
  <p>
    <Name>England</Name>
    <Val>London</Val>
  </p>
  <p>
    <Name>Spain</Name>
    <Val>Madrid</Val>
  </p>
</pairs>';

DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(100)=N'England';

SELECT
  Tab.Col.query('(p[Name=sql:variable("@param")]/Val)[1]') AS [Capital]
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('/pairs') Tab(Col)
```

Even better

```
SELECT
  p.value('Val[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Capital]
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('/pairs/p[Name=sql:variable("@param")]') One(p)
```

Or as a one liner

```
SELECT @MyXml.value('(/pairs/p[Name=sql:variable("@param")]/Val)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Capital]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even without complicated XPath queries like this:

```
select Tab.Col.value('Val[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Capital]
from @MyXML.nodes('/pairs/p') as Tab(Col)
where Tab.Col.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'England'
```

Comment: If you read all nodes and do the filter in a `WHERE` clause, this will lead to huge extra work. With a big XML (or with many entries in one go) the performance would be very bad probably. The *complicated XPath queries* allow to return only the enlements needed...

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the `<p>` tag in the nodes path and simplify your SELECT.
This gives a list of all Countries and Capitals:

```
SELECT
  T.c.value('(Name)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Country
 ,T.c.value('(Val)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Capital
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('/pairs/p') T(c)
```

The syntax is no different in the WHERE clause, so you can just apply a parameter there:

```
declare @param nvarchar(100) = 'England'
SELECT
  T.c.value('(Val)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Capital
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('/pairs/p') T(c)
WHERE T.c.value('(Name)[1]','nvarchar(100)') = @Param
```

Here is a complete test script that does both.

```
declare @MyXML xml;
SET @MyXML = 
'
<pairs>
  <p>
    <Name>France</Name>
    <Val>Paris</Val>
  </p>
  <p>
    <Name>England</Name>
    <Val>London</Val>
  </p>
  <p>
    <Name>Spain</Name>
    <Val>Madrid</Val>
  </p>
</pairs>
'
SELECT
  T.c.value('(Name)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Country
 ,T.c.value('(Val)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Capital
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('/pairs/p') T(c)

declare @param nvarchar(100) = 'England'
SELECT
  T.c.value('(Val)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Capital
FROM
  @MyXML.nodes('/pairs/p') T(c)
WHERE T.c.value('(Name)[1]','nvarchar(100)') = @Param
```

Comment: I would not apply the filter in a `WHERE` clause... If you read all nodes and do the filter at the end, it will lead to huge extra work. With a big XML (or with many entries in one go) the performance would be very bad probably.

Comment: @Shnugo I would suggest that when working with large XML datasets, the best approach is to drop the flattened dataset into a temp table, work on it there, then transform back into XML at the end.  For sets with < 10k rows this approach has been virtually instant for me.

Comment: I agree, if the XML is easy to be flattened out and if you are going to do several steps at once. But I disagree if you just want to read a value once. Just imagine a table with thousands of XMLs and I want to pick those where the Name is "England". You'd have to flatten all of them just to filter some tiny information...

Comment: @Shnugo agreed, if you have a large dataset and you just need to pick off one value, then this isn't the most efficient way.  But there are only about 200 countries in the world, so for this example I think it's going to work fine.

Comment: Just imagine a tabel with millions of rows. One XML column includes `Country` element and you want to filter for those from "England". Still working fine :-) ?

Comment: Honestly probably yes. But I haven't tested it. The asker didn't specify the table size or performance requirements. If you are running this kind of query against millions of rows then you have deeper problems.

Comment: *If you are running this kind of query against millions of rows then you have deeper problems* OK, that point is yours :-)